# Import list of IPs into DEVICE=eth0:X

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of IPs I would like to import into my Linux VPS. They are not an IP range.

How would I create a bash script that does this for me?

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

If they where my IP lists then it should create the two following files

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1
```

-

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=1.1.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

-

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:2
```

-

```
DEVICE=eth0:2
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=2.2.2.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
counter=`ls -1 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:* 2>/dev/null | cut -d : -f 2 | sort -n | tail -1`
if [ -z "$counter" ]
then
  counter=0
fi

for ip in `cat iplist.txt`
do
  counter=`expr $counter + 1`
  cat << EOM > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:${counter}
DEVICE=eth0:${counter}
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=${ip}
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
EOM
done
```

This will first find the highest numbered virtual interface on eth0, then create a new file for each line in `iplist.txt` starting from there with the appropriate values filled out.

If you want to overwrite the existing files, you can either do an `rm` first, or remove the counter logic, just set it to 0, and move your increment to the end of the loop instead o the start.

Comment: @Teddy291: See: [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)